# I cannot make an event listener inside object constructor to listen

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

When I scroll the div, basically nothing happens. The method `slideIt` gets fired once when the object is initiated and that is it. It is not listening to the scrolling event! any reason why would this happen?

```
function fixed_column_or_row(container_name){
    this.container_div=$(container_name);

    this.scrollable_div=this.container_div.find(".simplebar-content-wrapper");
    this.fixed_row=this.container_div.find(".fixed-row")
    this.fixed_column=this.container_div.find(".fixed-column")

    //the issue in this line
    this.scrollable_div.scroll(this.slideIt())

}

fixed_column_or_row.prototype.slideIt=function(){
     var scrollTop      = this.scrollable_div.scrollTop(),
     scrollLeft      = this.scrollable_div.scrollLeft();
     console.log("scrollTop")
     this.fixed_row.css({
         "margin-left": -scrollLeft
     });

     this.fixed_column.css({
         "margin-top": -scrollTop
      }); 

}
```

Comment: The expression `this.scrollable_div.scroll(this.slideIt())` **calls** that function. You need to pass a bound reference to the function instead: `this.scrollable_div.scroll(this.slideIt.bind(this))`.

Comment: @Pointy It has worked. please put it as answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common JavaScript mistake is to type in a function *call* when what's wanted is a reference to a function (for setting up an event handler, usually, but there are other similar cases).

Thus

```
  this.scrollable_div.scroll(this.slideIt());
```

will **call** the `this.slideIt()` function and pass the return value to the `.scroll` method, and that is clearly not what is desired. The `()` after `this.slideIt` is what causes that, so `this.slideIt` *without* `()` is necessary.

Now, with that done, the next problem will be that the relationship to `this` will be lost. [There are various questions on Stackoverflow with long, thorough answers about how `this` works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440)  Suffice to say here that what's necessary is to ensure that `this` is correctly set:

```
  this.scrollable_div.scroll(this.slideIt.bind(this));
```

(There are other ways of doing it, but that should work.)